# Java Atm machine (how to add notes)

Tags: java

I have to make a project (atm machine in java) in which the atm must support $20 and $50 notes. Requirments:

*It must support $20 and $50 notes.
It should be able to dispense only legal combinations of notes. For example, a request for $100 can be satisfied by either five $20 notes or two $50 notes. It is not required to present a list of options.
If a request cannot be satisfied due to failure to find a suitable combination of notes, it should report an error condition in some fashion. For example, in an ATM with only $20 and $50 notes, it is not possible to dispense $30.*

I cant find a solution to add the notes and i have done the following program.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class AtmMachine{

    private static Scanner in; 
    private static float balance = 200; 
    public static void main(String args[]){
        in = new Scanner(System.in);


        transaction();
    }

    private static void transaction(){


        int choice; 

        System.out.println("Please select an option"); 
        System.out.println("1. Withdraw");
        System.out.println("2. Balance");

        choice = in.nextInt();

        switch(choice){
            case 1:
                float amount; 
                System.out.println("Please enter amount to withdraw: "); 
                amount = in.nextFloat();
                if(amount > balance || amount == 0){
                    System.out.println("You have insufficient funds\n\n"); 
                    transaction(); 
                } else {

                    balance = balance - amount; 
                    System.out.println("You have withdrawn "+amount+" and your new balance is "+balance+"\n");
                    transaction(); 
                }
            break; 


           case 2:

                System.out.println("Your balance is "+balance+"\n");
                transaction(); 
            break;

            default:
                System.out.println("Invalid option:\n\n"); 
                transaction();
            break;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: What is your problem? Can you describe in prose how to split an amount into combinations of 20s and 50s? Can you, assuming that it is possible? Can you detect when it is not? What is your problem?

Comment: In order to find an algorithm, try acting stupid. If I ask for 110$ how would you try to give it in 50s and 20s? 50, 50, fail. 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, fail. 50, 20, 20, 20, success. What is the most blind, stupid, stubborn, narrow-minded way of doing this? If you can answer this, then you are 90% done for defining an algorithm.

Comment: You also need an exit point.

Comment: i see what you mean but i m beginner in java and i cant write this code which supports 50$ and 20$ notes. If someone can help me in order to write this code according to the requirments i said it would be really helpful

Comment: StackOverflow is a place to ask a specific question and receive an answer, not to get someone else to do your homework for you.

Comment: Hint: every number > 40 that’s divisible by 10 is valid in your assignment.

Comment: I assume that this is homework. Please state whether you would appreciate help according to the compromise described here: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions

Answer (score 1):

Since you are learning, writing code for you will not help you. I will help you by giving the crucial ideas. Assuming you want to extract X amount of money, you will need to check the following

1. Is X < 20? If so, then it is invalid.
2. Is X > balance? If so, then it is invalid.
3. Is X divisible with 10? If not, then it is invalid.

These are the simplest checks for validity. Now, if the validation passed the simplest checks, then you will need to check possible combinations, check all possible combinations around the target amount. Think of it that you will hand out m banknotes of 50$ and n banknotes of 20$. What are the possible combinations of m and n? Use these as variables and increase/decrease them. First increase m until you reach X. Did you reach it? Then put it into a set of results. Of course, use a variable with an appropriate data structure. Then repeat the following until m reaches -1:

decrease m
increase n until you reach or surpass X
if it is a solution, then store it among the possible solutions
set n to 0

Now, you have a set of solutions to choose from. Of course, the balance is incorrect in your program. You will need to know how many banknotes of 20$ and of 50$ you have. Okay, you have 200$ in total, but is it comprised from 5 * 20$ and 2 * 50$? Or is it comprised from 4 * 50$? As you can see, you will need to modify your members, your balance variable is too simplistic for the problem.

Now, since you have a set of solutions, you will need to choose the best solution. The best solution is the one which results in a state where the new m and n is closest to each-other. Choose the solution, reduce m and/or n accordingly and wait for the next extraction.

It is not a good idea to recursively call transaction again and again when you could put this simply into a while cycle.